# Events As json feed

Tags: asp.net, json, fullcalendar

I am pointing to an aspx (Events_json.aspx) page that generates a json string.  Here's the code:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'today',
            month: 'month',
            week: 'week',
            day: 'day'
        },
        events: 'Events_json.aspx',
        editable: true,
        droppable: true
      }  //etc.
```

My aspx page has the following directive:

```
<%@ Page ContentType="application/json" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Events_json.aspx.vb" Inherits="Events_json" %>
```

My sub-routine uses response.write to write out the event data:

```
                Do While dr.Read()
                EventID = dr("EventID")
                EventST = dr("EventST")
                EventET = dr("EventET")
                EventName = dr("EventName")
                ECBgColor = dr("ECBgColor")
                ECBdrColor = dr("ECBdrColor")
                str = str & "        {" & vbCrLf
                str = str & "            id: '" & EventID.ToString() & "'," & vbCrLf
                str = str & "            title: '" & ToHex(EventName) & "'," & vbCrLf
                str = str & "            start: '" & Format(EventST, doDate(EventST) + "T" + "HH:mm:ss").ToString() & "'," & vbCrLf
                str = str & "            end: '" & Format(EventET, doDate(EventET) + "T" + "HH:mm:ss").ToString() & "'," & vbCrLf
                str = str & "            backgroundColor: '" & ECBgColor.ToString() & "'," & vbCrLf
                str = str & "            borderColor: '" & ECBdrColor.ToString() & "'" & vbCrLf
                str = str & "        }," & vbCrLf
            Loop
            str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 3) & vbCrLf
            'str = str & "    }" & vbCrLf
            'str = str & "]," & vbCrLf
            Response.Write(str)
```

When I run this page, it produces a json string, but FireFox tells me there is a syntax error:  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 13 of the JSON data

When I run the page containing the FullCalendar script, no events will display.  When I copy and paste the output of events_json.aspx into the FullCalendar script, the events display on the calendar.

```
{
            id: '1',
            title: 'Test Event',
            start: '2017-9-25T10:00:00',
            end: '2017-9-25T11:00:00',
            backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc',
            borderColor: '#3c8dbc'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Test Event',
            start: '2017-9-26T10:00:00',
            end: '2017-9-26T11:00:00',
            backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc',
            borderColor: '#3c8dbc'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'Test Event',
            start: '2017-9-27T10:00:00',
            end: '2017-9-27T11:00:00',
            backgroundColor: '#3c8dbc',
            borderColor: '#3c8dbc'
        }
```

I do not understand why my call to the external page will not display events, but when I copy and paste the output of the external page into my calendar script, it works.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to roll your own json output, have you tried using [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Anchor_6) or similar?

Comment: don't create JSON by string concatenation. Too prone to syntax errors, especially if the values contain quote marks etc. Something like JSON.NET will serialise complex objects and lists directly into JSON with a line or two of code.

Comment: Anyway, what you've pasted as the JSON is not valid for fullCalendar, it must be wrapped in an array (using `[` and `]` at each end). What is the _exact_ output of your ASPX page? If you copy that _exact_ output as the right-hand-side of the `events:` option in your calendar, does it work or not?